# Adding a directory to the END of the load path in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, linux, bash, shell

Most answers I've seen on adding a directory to the load path in Ruby has been around using `unshift`, for eg:

```
$:.unshift File.dirname(__FILE__)
```

Can't you use `push` instead? Is it deliberate that most examples are using `unshift` vs. `push` when adding a directory to the load path?

Answer (score 1):

You can use either, but they're checked in order. `unshift` puts it in at the highest precedence, `push` as the lowest.

Normally this doesn't matter, you typically don't have duplicate module names, however if you want to override something you'll need to have your path earlier than the others. This makes `unshift` more desirable.

One thing to note is it's usually better to use `$LOAD_PATH` instead of `$:` so what you're doing is made more clear. Unless you're a Perl veteran you might not know off the top what `$:` is, and even then there's [a bunch of those variables that are very similar](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/doc/globals_rdoc.html).